# Pydrake: Evaluate PiecewisePolynomial with Symbolic Expression

Tags: python, drake

Is there a way to call `trajectory.value(t)` with `t` being a symbolic value and `trajectory` being a `pydrake.trajectories.PiecewisePolynomial` class? My use case would be using this `trajectory` inside a `DirectTranscription` cost explicitly. The cost I want to write is in the form of

J = Σ (x[k] - xd[k])^T Q (x[k] - xd[k])

s.t. x[k+1] = f(x[k], u[k])

I have tried doing this with simple `numpy` function for xd[k]. The skeleton would look like

```
xd = lambda t: np.sin(t)
dirtran = DirectTranscription(sys, sys.CreateDefaultContext(), horizon + 1)
x_k = dirtran.state()
t_k= dirtran.time()

x_k_decision = x_k - xd(t_k[0])
dirtran.AddRunningCost(x_k_decision.transpose() @ Q @ x_k_decision)
```

And everything works well. The solver will me a correct input trajectory that would track xd = sin(t). Now, I would want to use the same approach to track a trajectory coming out of a trajectory optimization such as direct collocation, to be exact, I want to track a trajectory that is the return of `ReconstructStateTrajectory`, which is a `PiecewisePolynomial`. The skeleton code would look like

```
xd = dircol.ReconstructStateTrajectory(result)
dirtran = DirectTranscription(sys, sys.CreateDefaultContext(), horizon + 1)
x_k = dirtran.state()
t_k= dirtran.time()

x_k_decision = x_k - xd.value(t_k[0])
dirtran.AddRunningCost(x_k_decision.transpose() @ Q @ x_k_decision)
```

Well, this would not work because `t_k` is actually a `(Variable 't(0)', Continuous)`, which is not the correct data type for `.value()`. I looked into the C++ source code and found out that the actual value for `t(0)` is only substituted in `DoAddRunningCost` with `SubstitutePlaceholderVariables`, only then we can evaluate `.value()` properly, but that's too late because the program already throw the error `The following environment does not have an entry for the variable t(0)` on line `x_k_decision = x_k - xd.value(t_k[0])`. One obvious solution would be writing the cost manually in a for loop and increment the time step myself (so I can use `.value()` function with a float, not a `Variable` placeholder) but that would kind of destroy the elegance of `DirectTranscription`. So is there anyway I can use `PiecewisePolynomial` in `AddRunningCost` ?

I am aware that we can change the coordinate so that we will solve for (x[k] - xd[k]) instead of x[k], but you normally would have take extra care when you write the `MathematicalProgram`. Being able to write the something like the first skeleton (with `xd = lambda t: np.sin(t)`) is really expressive (and it works, it's just that I can't find a way to make it work when the reference is a  solution coming out of `DirectCollocation`)

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known limitation](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/7304c8829603491f8e0123d936c0dd4036ba2302/common/trajectories/test/piecewise_polynomial_test.cc#L501-L503) of our `PiecewisePolynomial` class.

While I agree it might be elegant to fix this, I think it's almost never what you would want? If we were to make `symbolic::Expression` work for this, then the Expression it would return would be some nasty list of conditionals which check the symbolic variable `t` relative to the segment times, and only then has a nice polynomial expression in `t`.

If you skip over the logical portion (deciding which segment you are in), then the rest of the evaluation can be done with `Expression`. For example

```
import numpy as np
from pydrake.all import PiecewisePolynomial_, Variable, Expression

t = Variable('t')
pp = PiecewisePolynomial_[Expression].FirstOrderHold([0, 1, 2],
                                                np.random.rand(2, 3))
print(pp.getPolynomial(segment_index=0, row=0, col=0).EvaluateUnivariate(t))
```

returns an expression of the form

```
(0.99826839350064878 - 0.92294844889865379 * t)
```

You'll need [this PR](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/19118) to use it.

For the specific cost you're trying to add, I would think that using `AutoDiff` would be much more appropriate. The cast wasn't quite as simple as I would have liked, but it can be done:

```
import numpy as np
from pydrake.all import PiecewisePolynomial_, AutoDiffXd, Polynomial_

pp = PiecewisePolynomial_[float].FirstOrderHold([0, 1, 2],
                                                np.random.rand(2, 3))

def convert_polymat_to_autodiff(mat):
    mat_ad = np.empty(mat.shape, dtype=Polynomial_[AutoDiffXd])
    for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
        for j in range(mat.shape[1]):
            mat_ad[i, j] = Polynomial_[AutoDiffXd](
                mat[i, j].GetCoefficients())
    return mat_ad

polys = [
    convert_polymat_to_autodiff(pp.getPolynomialMatrix(i))
    for i in range(pp.get_number_of_segments())
]
pp_ad = PiecewisePolynomial_[AutoDiffXd](polys, pp.get_segment_times())

print(pp_ad.value(0.4))
```

Once you have that, then you could implement your cost as a generic function. Something like:

```
def cost_fun(vars):
    t = vars[0]
    x = vars[1:]
    if x.dtype == AutoDiffXd:
        x_decision = x - pp_ad.value(t)
    else:
        x_decision = x - pp.value(t)
    return x_decision.transpose() @ Q @ x_decision
```

Check out the nonlinear_program Drake tutorial if you haven't.